# Cannot connect to mongoDB Atlas any more

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a free database in Mongo Atlas. It used to work, but i don't know what I have changed, it does not work anymore. I'm sure I have entered the write password:

```
Ties-MacBook-Pro:devconnector chengtie$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net/test"  --username cheng123
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-01-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017/test?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
2020-02-11T14:38:51.292+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set monitor for Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017
2020-02-11T14:39:01.342+0100 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2020-02-11T14:39:01.342+0100 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
2020-02-11T14:39:16.861+0100 W NETWORK  [js] Unable to reach primary for set Cluster0-shard-0
2020-02-11T14:39:16.861+0100 I NETWORK  [js] Cannot reach any nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 2 checks in a row.
2020-02-11T14:39:16.861+0100 E QUERY    [js] Error: connect failed to replica set Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jnhgq.azure.mongodb.net.:27017 :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I tried to whitelist my IP, it still does not work:

[image]

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason: That's because I used a wireless "eduroam" who banned the connection... If I change to the wifi of my 4G Phone, it works...